# How to get Text from a website to a Texview

Tags: java, html, kotlin, text, get

Halo, friends?

I am very new to programming, I am trying to Learn Kotlin.

I am trying to get text from a web page to a text view in my activity.

e.g, in 'https://makeandsellsoap.blogspot.com/p/ratings.html' there is a text  on that page an I would like to get it to a text view.(read page content)

how can i start to go about this? Or is there anyone who can point me in the right direction. I've been trying examples from the internet for three days now to no avail.

I hope my question is wel  presented, if not please, forgive and correct me. I'll learn along the way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use [skrape.it](https://github.com/skrapeit/skrape.it) for scraping contents of webpage using specified classes/id/tags. And then once you got 'em you can change texts on textview or dynamically create textviews :)

Comment: Or you can use https://jsoup.org/ - another HTML parsing library.